# compass based sass, sprites plugin make webkit-special Pseudo-Elements wrong

Tags: css, sass

I have one img/icon folder which contains the scroll-btn-end.png in my web project, I write the scss file :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
   @include icons-sprite(scroll-btn-end);
}
```

but in the generated css file it's :

```
:increment:end::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background-image: url('../img/icons-sd4a90ad578.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

why in the generated css file , Pseudo-Elements's order wrong ?
is it a compass sprites plugin bug ?